# How to interpret GCM response codes for Android app?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We're using push notifications for our Android app. On 1 day, we're seeing

```
-39 messages with the GCM response code of HTTP 200 - OK and 
-16 messages with the GCM response code of HTTP 200 - Not Registered
```

Does "Not Registered" relate to the number of uninstalls we have for the app?

Furthermore, within the 39 with OK status, we're seeing:

```
-30 are "Stored"
-9 are "Sent"
```

What is the difference between stored and sent? Do stored messages mean the app was offline so it wasn't yet sent? Are there other explanations for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the official Android GCM docs

"When a 3rd-party server posts a message to GCM and receives a message ID back, it does not mean that the message was already delivered to the device. Rather, it means that it was accepted for delivery. What happens to the message after it is accepted depends on many factors.

In the best-case scenario, if the device is connected to GCM, the screen is on, and there are no throttling restrictions (see Throttling), the message will be delivered right away.

If the device is connected but idle, the message will still be delivered right away unless the `delay_while_idle` flag is set to `true`. Otherwise, it will be stored in the GCM servers until the device is awake. And that's where the `collapse_key` flag plays a role: if there is already a message with the same collapse key (and registration ID) stored and waiting for delivery, the old message will be discarded and the new message will take its place (that is, the old message will be collapsed by the new one). However, if the collapse key is not set, both the new and old messages are stored for future delivery. Collapsible messages are also called send-to-sync messages.

Note: There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync."

For more details please refer to http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

Comment: We're seeing a majority of messages in stored. So the messages that are currently in stored can be transferred to sent once the device is awake?

Comment: @sharataka Yes, if the device wakes up during "time_to_live" period it will be received all stored messages (if stored messages count < 100) or all stored messages will be dropped if device wakes up after "time_to_live" period.